# Javascript Get data-type tag value

Tags: javascript, html, types, prototype, custom-data-attribute

I would like to be able to retrieve the `data-type`, which is a new HTML5 tag name (or any custom tag name for that matter) with pure javascript. The context in which I would need to access this data is from within a loop of an elements childNodes.

```
var children = document.getElementById('foo').childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
    var dataType = children[i].dataType //This does not work.
}
```

Is there some way to prototype `childNodes` so that any element retrieved with that tag will have a `dataType` function attached to it so that the above code would in fact work?

I figure I'll have to use `children[i].outerHTML` to get the element's raw HTML and then a regular expression to actually put the value from the element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you mean getting data from `data-*` attributes

```
var children = document.getElementById('foo').childNodes;
var childrenLength = children.length;

for(var i=0; i<childrenLength; i++) {
    var dataType = children[i].getAttribute('data-type');
}
```

Comment: Or that. Looks alot easier than my approach haha.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on the subject, you'll find that the standard defines a simpler way than `.getAttribute`: a [DOMStringMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap) which can be read using a [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

In short that means that you can do this

```
var dataType = children[i].dataset.dataType;
```

Or you can set the `dataset` to a variable like the following, which is handy when you're getting several data attributes from an element

```
var dataSet = children[i].dataset,
    dataType = dataSet.dataType;
```